# Visualforce: apex:pageBlockTable Only Populates Column Headers

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I am using `pageBlockTable` to create a table that displays the output of fields entered on a previous Visualforce page.

The table will not display past the column headers. Perhaps pageBlockTable should not be used for this? Please see image below.

[image]

Visualforce Code:

```
             <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Prospect_Profile__c}" var="pp">
                  <apex:column headerValue="Bank Relationship"/>
                      <apex:outputField value="Loans: "/>
                      <apex:outputField value="Depository: "/>
                      <apex:outputField value="Treasury Mgmt: "/>
                      <apex:outputField value="International Services: "/>
                      <apex:outputField value="Mortgage: "/>
                  <apex:column headerValue="Current Provider"/>
                      <apex:outputField value="pp.CurPro_Loans__c"/>
                      <apex:outputField value="pp.CurPro_Depository__c"/>
                      <apex:outputField value="pp.CurPro_Treasury_Mgmt__c"/>
                      <apex:outputField value="pp.CurPro_International_Services__c"/>
                      <apex:outputField value="pp.CurPro_Mortgage__c"/>
                  <apex:column headerValue="Other Providers"/>
                      <apex:outputField value="pp.OthPro_Loans__c"/>
                      <apex:outputField value="pp.OthPro_Depository__c"/>
                      <apex:outputField value="pp.OthPro_Treasury_Mgmt__c"/>
                      <apex:outputField value="pp.OthPro_International_Services__c"/>
                      <apex:outputField value="pp.OthPro_Mortgage__c"/>
             </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap inside `<apex:column>`

```
           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Prospect_Profile__c}" var="pp">
              <apex:column headerValue="Bank Relationship">
                  <apex:outputField value="Loans: "/>
                  <apex:outputField value="Depository: "/>
                  <apex:outputField value="Treasury Mgmt: "/>
                  <apex:outputField value="International Services: "/>
                  <apex:outputField value="Mortgage: "/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Current Provider">
                  <apex:outputField value="pp.CurPro_Loans__c"/>
                  <apex:outputField value="pp.CurPro_Depository__c"/>
                  <apex:outputField value="pp.CurPro_Treasury_Mgmt__c"/>
                  <apex:outputField value="pp.CurPro_International_Services__c"/>
                  <apex:outputField value="pp.CurPro_Mortgage__c"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Other Providers">
                  <apex:outputField value="pp.OthPro_Loans__c"/>
                  <apex:outputField value="pp.OthPro_Depository__c"/>
                  <apex:outputField value="pp.OthPro_Treasury_Mgmt__c"/>
                  <apex:outputField value="pp.OthPro_International_Services__c"/>
                  <apex:outputField value="pp.OthPro_Mortgage__c"/>
              </apex:column>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Ratan you are a legend!

Comment: Hold up mistake on my end, everything is working now. Thanks again Ratan!

Comment: @Mercury86 add  you updated code in question let me check